# javascript/jquery survey progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to have a progress bar advance every time a user answers a question (even with multiple questions on a page). So I set up to variables at the beginning/top of the page:

```
<div id="progress"><p id="counter"><span id="percent">0%</span></p></div>
<script>var count = 0;
var total = 79;
var progress = 0;</script>
```

Then I do a bit of jQuery for most of the questions with radio inputs, and they work fine (and don't increase count if you change your option on the question). However, with checkboxes and selects, it's not working as well:

```
$('input[name="race"]').one("click", function(){
    var n = 0;
    if (n==0) {
        n = ++n;
        count = ++count;
        progress = count/total;
        $("#counter").css("width", progress);
        $("#percent").text(progress + "%")
    }
});
```

If I remove the if-statement, the function works, but it increases `count` for each checkbox.

I would also like to trim `progress` to just 3 characters, but it doesn't like `progress = progress.slice(0,3);` or `progress = progress.substr(0,10)

Answer (score 1):

For the if statement it needs another = sign. That should get the logic right. Oh and you set n as a string in the line above, but compare it to an int in the line below. You will need to choose one or the other. From the line n=n++ I believe you will want to change var n = 0; instead of var n ="0";
Then for the progress variable you are trying to take the substr of an int. Thus you would need to convert the int to a string before trimming. But as an int it shouldn't need to be trimmed anywise.

Comment: As you imply: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: I thought from php that it should be `==` and not just one, but the example I found on w3schools used just one :s well, I tried removing the quotes from around the 0s and using `==`, but it's still triggering `count` to increment :(

Comment: oh! I just realised what is probably happening: every time the listener is activated, `n` is re-set to 0! So…any idea how do I get a variable that's re-usable (for each question), yet doesn't reset itself?

Comment: @jacob You could simply instantiate the variable as zero outside of the onClick function.

Comment: so i would dynamically create a variable? I'm not sure how this would be done in js (in php might do this with a session variable, but i don't think js has those).

Comment: @jacob just instantiate the variable before the line: $('input[name="race"]').one("click",function(){ |||||| That way it will have a value prior to the click event and won't be reset on ever click event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only radio buttons, checkboxes and selects. This should do the trick

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var progress = 0;
    //need this to check if the question has not been answered before
    var questions = {
        "pref1": 0,
        "pref2":0,
        "pref3":0
    }
    $( function() {
        $("#progress").text(progress)
        $("input, select").change( function() {
            el_name = $(this).attr("name");


            switch (this.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                case "select":
                    field =$("[name='"+el_name+"']");
                    val = (field.val() === ""  || !field.val()) ? null: field.val();
                    break;
                case "input":
                    field =$("[name='"+el_name+"']:checked");
                    val = field.length;
                    break;
            }

            if (val) {

                if (!questions[el_name]) {
                    progress = progress +1;
                    questions[el_name]=1
                }

            } else {


                questions[el_name]=0
                progress = (progress > 0)?progress-1:0;


            }

            $("#progress").text(progress)
        })
    })
</script>
<div id="progress">
</div>
<input type="radio" name="pref1" value="one">
one
<input type="radio" name="pref1" value="two">
two
<br>
<select name="pref2">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pref3" value="one">
one
<input type="checkbox" name="pref3" value="two">
two
```

Comment: oow, so I'd only need to have this listed once? (Shouldn't the script appear after the form?)